# Minecraft launcher Won't Work On ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: minecraft

I have Minecraft 1.15.2 java edition

When I press The **Play** Button, Then a Window Opens saying:

```
GLFW error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig

Please make sure you have up-to-date drivers (see aka.ms/mcdriver for instructions).
```

I Dont Know Why That But I Now You can Help Me
And Thank You

Comment: I have equivalent problem with other application, not solved yet but I think I am in the path. Run this command `glxinfo |grep "OpenGL version"` just to know what you have. Install/upgrade from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa everything related to opengl mesa. But here it still says OpenGL version 2.1, this probably means that now I need to try to upgrade my graphics drivers, as the message says in the error you got.

Comment: I think there is no hope for me. The newest intel graphics drivers `xserver-xorg-video-intel` will still fail with that error. Apparently, a notebook is not a good purchase as we can't upgrade the graphics hardware after some years as we can easily do with a desktop machine :(. If yours is a notebook too, then you may be out of luck too...

Answer (score 1):

On terminal, run :-

```
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5
```

...and then run Minecraft. Should solve it.

Comment: Please, could you [edit] your answer adding some details? Is it a command to run in the terminal (and how many times? Everytime you want to lauch the game or only one time)? Or is it a line to put in a dot file? What does this command do?